# lighttpd on Mac 10.5 - can't find lighttpd.conf

Tags: macos, lighttpd

I just did a clean build and reinstall of lighttpd 1.4.20 on Mac OS X 10.5 and I can't find the configuration file.

My goal was to install lighty to a single directory instead of being spread around, so I used the following commands successfully:

```
./configure --prefix="/usr/local/lighttpd"
sudo make clean
sudo make
```

This successfully put the binaries and libs in /usr/local/lighttpd/ like I wanted. However, the configuration file was not installed at /usr/local/lighttpd/doc/lightppd.conf as indicated in the INSTALL doc.

Any idea where it would be? Or did I miss an option on ./configure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stobor's solution should help you (just copy $SOURCEDIR/doc/lighttpd.conf to /usr/local/etc/ or wherever you want it, and then specify on the command-line where the file is whenever you launch lighttpd.)

If you install this kind of thing often, perhaps you want to take a look at [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/). I note that they have lighttpd, both 1.4.26 and 1.5.0 (devel). I have been very happy using MacPorts to install UNIXy stuff on my Powerbook G4 with Mac OS X 10.5.

Answer (score 0):

The way I read it, the [INSTALL file](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/repositories/entry/lighttpd/tags/lighttpd-1.4.20/INSTALL) seems to say that you have to manually create the lighttpd.conf file, by copying the one from $SOURCEDIR/doc/lighttpd.conf, not $INSTALLDIR/doc/lighttpd.conf - Have you looked there?